# C Programming Passing Arguments by lpszArgs

Tags: c

I am using **WinMain** in a **C** executable to add a registry entry for **Windows**.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE previnst,
                   LPSTR lpszArgs, int Mode){

    HKEY hMykey; //Handle to your key
    DWORD pDWDisp; // Ignore for this
    LONG lRes; // Test Success
    char prog[] = "C:\\WINNT\\system32\\sol.exe"; //Key to launch

    lRes = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                   "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\run",
                   0,"Whatever",REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
                   NULL,&hMykey,&pDWDisp); // Open a key for edit

    if(lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS){
        MessageBox(0,"Error opening key","",MB_OK);
        exit(0);// Shutdown on fail
    }

    lRes = RegSetValueEx(hMykey,"Sol",0,REG_SZ,
                       (LPBYTE)prog,strlen(prog)+1);// Add your key value

    if(lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS){
        MessageBox(0,"Error saving record","",MB_OK);
        RegCloseKey(hMykey);
        exit(0);// Shutdown on fail
    }

    MessageBox(0,"Success!! Registry value recorded","",MB_OK);
    RegCloseKey(hMykey);
    return 0;
}
```

For traditional **main** function, **argv** is handy to separate passed arguments. But for **lpszArgs** it needs to be set as a single string, as far as I understand.

I can pass a **lpszArgs** string to **WinMain** as "executable + file" combination separated by empty space:

```
executable="C:\\WINNT\\system32\\sol.exe"
file="C:\\test.txt"

"\"C:\\WINNT\\system32\\sol.exe\" \"C:\\test.txt\""
```

but how am I suppose to get those values inside **WinMain** function?

Is it supposed to split the **lpszArgs** by empty space and get those two arguments or is there any other better way you can recommend?